# Calling val() on a select sometimes returns null

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

This is my `select`. When I try `$(".test").val()` it returns `null` sometimes,. I can't understand what is wrong with it.

```js
console.log($('.test').val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="test">
  <option class="option" selected value="1">1</option>
  <option class="option" value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What do you mean by sometimes? It works for me.

Comment: I added your code in a snippet - as you can see it works fine. The only way I could see this not working is if there is another `.test` element in the DOM which appears before this.

Comment: This would happen if you *don't* have `selected` in your html *or* if you have some code that clears the value:  `$(".test").val("");console.log($('.test').val());` (==null)

Comment: Where do you load your scripts? `<head>` or before `</body>`?

Comment: Ensure DOM is available before run the JS code.

Answer (score 0):

What about change test from class to id?
It ll be unique so your DOM 'll not interference with it . Because I think this is the problem for the undefined return

```js
console.log($('#test').val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="test">
  <option class="option" selected value="1">1</option>
  <option class="option" value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

---

In your code you have a `select` element with some `options`. But as your `JQuery` code, you're selecting the value of `select` element.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="test">
 <option class="option" selected value="1">1</option>
 <option class="option" value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

If your `select` element is like below.

```
<select value="something"></select>
```

Your code may output something.

### Solution

---

But, you've to get the `value` of the `option` which is selected.

Now, try this code.

```
console.log($('#test option:selected').val());
```

You'll find your desired output (1).

You can read it from [learn.jquery](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-get-the-text-value-of-a-selected-option/)